# upload data with HTTP method POST or PUT

Tags: c++, c, http, file-upload, https

I'm working with STM32-microcontroller and C-languege and want to send to and receive the data from my website. I can receive the .txt file with the "GET" method from website via this code:

```
static const char http_request[] = "GET "WEBSITE_SUB_ADDRESS" HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: "WEBSITE_ADDRESS"\r\n\r\n";
net_sock_send(socket, (uint8_t *) http_request, len);
net_sock_recv(socket, (uint8_t *) buffer + read, NET_BUF_SIZE - read);
```

Now I want to send or upload the data to the website in a file with http-method (POST or PUT, ...). How can I do it?

Comment: Maybe this can help ? https://github.com/LiteOS/LiteOS_Connect_to_3rd_Cloud/blob/master/liteos_to_awscloud/liteos_awscloud_%E6%A5%BC%E5%AE%87%E6%B8%85%E6%B4%81%E5%B0%8F%E7%AE%A1%E5%AE%B6/Huawei_LiteOS_AWS%20_KEIL/Common/Shared/Src/http_util.c

Comment: What does your attempt to do a POST or PUT look like? Hopefully we can help correct it.

Comment: My goal is, that with http-methodes, be able to upload the data in a file(eg. txt-File) in server.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to decide if you want to use POST or PUT.

> The PUT method completely replaces whatever currently exists at the target URL with something else. With this method, you can create a new resource or overwrite an existing one given you know the exact Request-URI. ...In short, the PUT method is used to create or overwrite a resource at a particular URL that is known by the client.
>
> The HTTP POST method is used to send user-generated data to the web server. For example, a POST method is used when a user comments on a forum or if they upload a profile picture. A POST method should also be used if you do not know the specific URL of where your newly created resource should reside. ...In short, the POST method should be used to create a subordinate (or child) of the resource identified by the Request-URI.
> from https://www.keycdn.com/support/put-vs-post

While connected to the server you would send a HTTP header just as you have done with the GET request that would look somthing like this:

```
POST /test HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: www.myServer.com\r\n
Content-Type: text/plain\r\n
Content-Lenght: 8\r\n
Accept: */*\r\n
\r\n
someData
```

You might also want to check if the server recived the message by looking at the header that is sent back to you, it should include `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`.

Edit: to get it into a file try `/test/mytext.txt` but i dont have a way of testing if this works

A good place to test the request is [Post Test Server V2](https://ptsv2.com/). hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

@Flynn Harrison

I tested your method as follows:

```
static const char http_request[] =   "POST "SUB_ADDRESS" HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                                     "Host: "HOST_ADDRESS"\r\n\r\n"
                                     "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n"
                                     "Content-Lenght: 13\r\n"
                                     "Accept: */*\r\n"
                                     "\r\n"
                                     "Data for Write Test";
```

and then:

```
net_sock_setopt(socket, "tls_server_name", (uint8_t*)HOST_ADDRESS, sizeof(HOST_ADDRESS));
net_sock_open(socket, HOST_ADDRESS, TIME_SOURCE_HTTP_PORT, 0);
net_sock_send(socket, (uint8_t *) http_request, len);
net_sock_recv(socket, (uint8_t *) buffer + read, NET_BUF_SIZE - read);
```

When I tried "/test.txt" at SUB_ADDRESS, I get the HTTP / 1.1 200 OK message but immediately after receiving the file contents, in the same buffer, I receive the HTTP / 1.1 400 Bad Request message and I do not see any changes to the file. My response from server is as follows:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

.

.

.

This is a Test.... (Text-File Content)

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\nDate: Fri, 09 Aug 2019 09:03:56

.

.

.

In the site you mentioned, the POST method works well but its mechanism is not clear which I can use. I tried to test the POST method with this site and my device but got error "411 Length Required".